# Disable time seek in AVPlayer

Tags: swift, tvos

I am using the AVPlayer for playing very short videos in tvOS. At the moment, when I touch the remote, the timeline of the videos shows up and I am able to fast forward and backward. Is there a way to completely disable this, i.e. force the user to see the clip from beginning to end without being able to forward/backward/pause/...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an easy solution for the problem: from the AVPlayerViewController, one can set the property showsPlaybackControls to false. So for example in the constructor:

```
class PlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.showsPlaybackControls = false
    }
}
```

Then the controls don't appear anymore and forward/backward/play/pause don't work anymore as well.

Answer (score 8):

`yourPlayerController.requiresLinearPlayback = true` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
self.playerController.setValue(true, forKey: "requiresLinearPlayback")
```

Answer (score 1):

On tvOS you can just call `playerViewController.requiresLinearPlaybackSelector = true` directly but in case you're finding this answer via Google and looking for iOS:

There is also the same api (currently private in iOS 11) where you can set `requiresLinearPlayback` to true or false. You'll crash if you try and call it on iOS 10 though (and possibly future iOS versions if the private api is changed) so DO NOT blindly call `setValue:forKey:` as other have suggested.

Instead use a selector to make sure it exists and then safely call it:

```
    let requires = true // or false
    let requiresLinearPlaybackSelector = #selector(setRequiresLinearPlayback(_:))
    if playerViewController.responds(to: requiresLinearPlaybackSelector) {
        playerViewController.perform(requiresLinearPlaybackSelector, with: requires ? 1 : nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the AVPlayerViewController, if you use another ViewController and initialize an AVPlayer and add it as a subview, you won't get the time seek.

If you want to disable play/pause you can override play/pause button in [pressedEnded](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH16-SW1).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't solve the problem in the way you suggested, but it led me to the right answer, it was not clear for me before that AVPlayerViewController is responsible for the time seek.